# Sitecore CD instance - Restrict access to Sitecore folder without blocking keepalive.aspx?

Tags: security, scaling, content-delivery, iis

I have a CD/CM site which I hardened by restricting access to Sitecore by adding "sitecore" to the Hidden Segments in the Request Filtering section in IIS (second answer [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-do-i-disable-sitecore-access-on-a-content-delivery-server)). However, this has blocked access to /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx, and I am getting errors logged every time the keepalive service runs.

Is there a way to block the entire sitecore folder on CD *except* for sitecore/services? I expect I could add each subfolder to the Hidden Segments but I'm not sure if there's a better solution.

Comment: The [other answer](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/218/135) is similar to what we use, an IIS Rewrite rule which `negates` the service folder acess (i.e. still allows request access to items in that folder)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a way to do what you are asking because `deny` permissions are always stronger than `grant` permissions, so the instruction to deny access to `/sitecore/*` would beat the instruction to grant access to `/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx`.

Instead, I would recommend following Sitecore's [Security Hardening Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/sitecore_security_hardening_guide-sc75-usletter.pdf) (section 1.5):

> To restrict access to the client interfaces, we recommend that you
>   implement IP-based security restrictions or disable Anonymous IIS
>   access to the `/sitecore/admin`, `/sitecore/login`, `/sitecore/shell`
>   folders and to the `/sitecore/default.aspx` page.

Also related (from the same section):

> The /sitecore/service folder should be excluded from the IIS
>   restrictions because it contains a number of service ASPX pages that
>   are used by Sitecore to report various conditions that can occur in
>   the application, such as, 404 Page Not Found or 403 Forbidden to the
>   web client.
>
> However, you can move the files from the /sitecore/service folder to
>   the /sitecore folder. If you move the files, you must also update the
>   following settings in the web.config file:
>
> - ErrorPage
> - NoAccessUrl
> - NoLicenseUrl
> - LayoutNotFoundUrl
> - ItemNotFoundUrl
> - LinkItemNotFoundUrl

Comment: Yup, I've always preferred IP-based security restrictions as well since you can then access the Sitecore files from specific IP addresses if you need to check ShowConfig.aspx or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can also handle that with authorization in web.config:

```
<!-- Deny users access to internal paths -->
<location path="sitecore">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="xsl">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore modules">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore/service">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <!--heartbeat, keepalive, ect. must be accessible-->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="sitecore/shell/Webservice/Service.asmx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <!--allow webservice-->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Best regards
Dirk